# What practices are prohibited by Protestant churches but not explicitly prohibited by the Bible?

Tags: protestantism, reformed-theology, tradition, religious-practice

I would like examples of practices that are prohibited by Protestant churches (consider only Protestant churches that accept the **Westminster Confession of Faith**) but are not explicitly prohibited in the Bible. The examples I found are the following:

- Baptize yourself (in my perception no church allows you to baptize yourself. The baptism of one person is performed by another)
- Suicide
- Masturbation

I am looking for these examples to identify inferences that are used when interpreting the Bible.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  It would be helpful if you could specify exactly which denominations you seek answers from.  As you must realise, there are many different Protestant denominations.  The term "Evangelical" is extremely broad.  Please take our tour to find out more: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Lesley Thanks for the tip. I've already edited it!

Comment: For this question to work it would really need to pick a single denomination.

Comment: @curiousdannii I edited the question! Could you open the question, please?

Comment: Do you want an internal or external perspective? Asking what Reformed Protestants think about themselves is fine, asking what other denominations think about them might open up the question to arguments.

Comment: @curiousdannii I want an internal perspective!

Comment: I can think of the opposite of your question...ie an accepted practise that is not specifically mandated in the Bible. The changing of the Sabbath from the Seventh Day to the first day of the week. There is no where in the Bible that specifically says "the Sabbath is the first day of the week", and yet a large majority of Christian denominations choose to worship on that day

Comment: Different Protestants have different views. The list of practices that are not prohibited in the Bible but banned by at least some part of Protestantism is too long to go into. Smoking, drinking, gambling, dancing, going to the theatre, voting Democrat, serving in the military, playing music...

Comment: @Adam I've got a few more for you. Driving cars, using the internet, voting, watching television, using 3 field crop rotation, owning a clock. All widely accepted. None specifically mandated in the Bible.

Comment: @Adam I think the reason Churches practise sabath in the First day was because Jesus Christ rose on the First Day. The disciples also met on the First Day of the week after the ressurection of Christ.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of this.  As someone stated in a comment, there are literally scores if not hundreds of denominations, just within Evangelical Protestantism. Plus many more if you include all the branches of mainline protestant churches.  In many of these churches, the prohibition is in their doctrinal statement, and in others, it's not part of the statement of faith but strict church protocol or tradition which they say is based on principles.

Two examples I can think of that fit your description.

1. alcohol in any form.  This is not explicitly in the doctrinal statement but widely condemned, prohibited in Nazarene Churches, most Southern Baptist, Bible Methodist, Church of God Holiness and many Pentecostal churches.

2.Another example is that many churches have a custom of prohibiting anyone from taking communion who has not been baptized.  No clear scriptural support of this, but they make the case based on baptism being an act of obedience in the New Testament and Communion an extension of this. This is a common practice in Baptist and Evangelical churches in Poland, Denmark and even some in the US.

Another example is that some churches only allow people to take communion who are members. This was the practice of a reformed PCA church I attended. It was very offensive to guests who couldn't take part in the Lord's supper.  There are most often presented as individual church policies, which usually are determined at the local level. This is the case in many Evangelical Free Church of America churches, which is a denomination, but every local congregation is entirely autonomous and self led.
One of the biggest examples is the ban/ prohibition of musical instruments in the Church of Christ. Instruments are mentioned all through the scriptures, and there is no ban or prohibition anywhere against instruments. The reasoning is that there was no mention of NT churches using musical instruments - so it's an argument from silence.

You mentioned the example of self- baptism, but on the topic of baptism, many Protestant churches will prohibit a parent or friend from baptizing someone, or even the person who led him or her to Christ, and this is nowhere in scripture, but the reasoning is that this is the responsibility of an appointed elder or deacon, and that allowing a member to baptize is risky. This is common in Nazarene churches, some Pentecostal churches, some Baptist churches, and even some Evangelical churches.  The church I currently attend is Baptist, and they only have staff pastors baptize. This was also the case in one Evangelical Free church, and also the case in a reformed church I attended.

Comment: While people debate how the verses should best be interpreted, everyone would admit that 1 Timothy 2:12 can easily be read, at least on the surface, as saying that women shouldn't teach men. So that's not an example for this question.

Comment: I totally agree with your interpretation. Yet  there are protestant denominations with women pastors. Lutheran and Episcopal that I know of and I think some Methodists. Weird huh.

Comment: Weird or not, it's not what this question concerns, which is prohibitions of Protestants with no textual support.

Comment: I edited the post, - but I had already given several other examples anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few in my denomination

Eailer in the 20th century Television was apassive prohibition and the reasoning behind this was due to the unedifying media productions, also this was somewhat a valid argument then, The church tends to ignore it now due to the fact that what you see onnthe streets is far more unedifying than what the media shows.

Another is wearing of earings and jeweries and Makeup. Though there are verses in the bible that discourages the use of earings Jacob35:4, Ex32:2 there are also verses thats encourages them as being seen as symbol a blessing and beauty Ezek16:12, Prov25:12, Personally I see it as a form of modesty in line with what Paul said in 1Tim2:9.

Marital counselling, commitee and procedure is another practice my church does which isnt explicitely stated in the Bible. The Man is expected not to meet the Lady but instead firstly inform his Pastor of his spiritual conviction and Leading to the Lady, after which he is reffered to the Marraige committee which checks to see if the Lady is already engaged, If not the Man is then scheduled to meet with the Lady to discuss his intentions. The major reasons for this is to create order in the Church.

Wearing of head covering is another modest practise that makes the church look less like the world, although Paul mentions this for Women who have shaved thier Hair, It's not explicitely stated to wear an head covering but my Church practises it.

I would appreciate clarifications on some of my Points.

To address your points.
Sucide - The Bible obviously speacks about murder
Masturbation - This is obvious as it is a result of not being able to mortify your flesh. Also most times it comes with lustful thoughts towards an opposite sex.

Thanks and have a prosperous and more Peaceful Year ahead

Edit
Denomination is a Pentecostal Church(Deeper Life Bible Church)

Comment: I have added the specific name of my denomination. Thanks